How to make footnotes have a single margin
I have the following simplified code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    \section{introduction}
    section one\footnote{book number one} is created\footnote{This is a long sentence
    This is a long sentence This is a long sentence This is a long sentence This is a long
    sentence This is a long sentence This is a long sentence This is a long sentence } And
    then there is the other reference and then there\footnote{book number two} is that one
    and then that one and then there is that one and then that one and then there is that
    one\footnote{book number three} and then that one
\end{document}

The footnotes resulting from this look like this:

How can I make them have the same margin, just like in this photo?


What about if a footnote has more than one paragraph?

I have never seen one. Anything that is organised and visually pleasing to the eye is fine I think..

The answer is similar but the question is different. The other new thing introduced here is the \footnotemargin agument by Mady Yuvi below.

Please try with:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
    \section{introduction}
    section one\footnote{book number one} is created\footnote{This is a long sentence
    This is a long sentence This is a long sentence This is a long sentence This is a long
    sentence This is a long sentence This is a long sentence This is a long sentence } And
    then there is the other reference and then there\footnote{book number two} is that one
    and then that one and then there is that one and then that one and then there is that
    one\footnote{book number three} and then that one
\end{document}



Excellent! But how can I reduce the horisontal distance between the number and the footnote?

You can modify the value \footnotemargin10pt, as per your wish

Default value is \footnotemargin1.8em

Thanks, that's exactly what I want!
